# 'Inferential data' and the Secure Software Development Life Cycle

Tags: sdlc

As part of exam revision I am studying past exam papers - One question that keeps popping up is related to 'Inferential Data' or 'Inference'

A typical example might be...

**"Discuss the term inference and describe what steps a secure programmer might take to prevent it occurring (use code snippets to aid your answer)."**

I know inferential data can be defined as data that is derived from a record set that a user shouldn't have access too, but can anyone help with additional information that would maybe assist me in exploring this question further.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

https://people.eecs.ku.edu/~saiedian/710/Lectures/ch05.ppt

check out this link gives examples and mitigation, take a look at the note sections of the slides 23,24,25.